# How to remove underline from title in custom action bar

Tags: android

I have added a custom action bar as i need a bottom border like this

**layout/myActivity.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:theme="@style/customActionBar"
       android:id="@+id/tbCustomActionBar"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**drawable/custom_action_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item>
     <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
         <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
     </shape>
 </item>
 <item android:top="-3dp" android:right="-3dp" android:left="-3dp">
     <shape>
         <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
         <stroke
            android:width="1dp"
            android:color="@color/actionBarBorder" />
     </shape>
 </item>
</layer-list>
```

**values/style.xml**

```
<resources>
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
 </style>
 <style name="customActionBar"
    parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_action_bar</item>
</style>
```

But this gives me a bottom border on title as well, and i only want it on Action bar. I think its because style is also applied on title, but i only want to show it under Action bar is there a way to remove it or a better way to do this?

*This is how it looks*

[image]

Comment: please try removing stroke from custom_action_bar

Comment: @AmruthaSaj it removes the line from both Title and ActionBar

Comment: then try defining custom textview inside toolbar

Comment: @AmruthaSaj will try to

Comment: @AmruthaSaj i did same thing happened

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `android:background="@drawable/custom_action_bar"` instead of theme  worked. Since theme applied to all the children inside toolbar and every view had border

Answer (score 0):

if you want just bottom border of toolbar you dont need to make custom toolbar you can achieve this just by using android:elevation="1dp"..for Example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="1dp">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Good idea with elevation but i want a 1dp solid border with color.

Answer (score 0):

Check your TextView, if you used

`android:inputType="text"` change into

`android:inputType="none"` or remove `android:inputType` from your textview..

If you are using `inputType` inside your textview this problem will occures.

Comment: The thing is i didn't use my TextView (i think it uses default `parent="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar`) and that is causing the problem (maybe wrong), will test this

Comment: I tried like that same thing added new TextView try to add what you said (try it without) but still getting underline under Text

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure.But you can try this.Change this in custom_action_bar.xml

```
<stroke
        android:width="0dp" // make it 0dp from 1 dp
        android:color="@color/actionBarBorder" />
```

Comment: This removed the borders on both